# What effect will red oxide primer have between a shipping container and a concrete slab over the top?

Tags: roofing, rust-proofing

I have a painted shipping container steel roof in average condition and plan to pour a 3.5 inch concrete slab on top. What effect will using red oxide resistant primer, as used in the tropics, bring to the project?

Our plan is to have the concrete serve as a patio. It will be on top of two 40' containers welded side by side reinforced with heavy steel mesh and fiberglass additive. The overall roof measurement is 16'x 32'. The centerline is 8'x 32' and is the strongest point sharing common walls. The plan is to pour 4" along the centerline tapering to 2" at the outside walls to insure rain runoff.

Comment: Are you going to put reinforcing in the concrete? Without doing calculations, i would be concerned a little bit about the weight. Recall that they are designed to carry weight on the floor. And when they are stacked, the weight is transferred in the corners.  Finally, why. The roof will easily last a few decades. Painted properly it is not going to rust.

Comment: Putting concrete over steel may precipitate the failure of the steel.   They did that on some museum ships for external decks and found out it was a "really bad idea" afterwards.

Comment: I'd lay a couple dozen coats of roofing tar over it rather than a layer of primer if you must do this.....

Answer (score 4):

### Concrete is wet by nature.  Wet + steel = fail.

Concrete is porous to water - that is its nature.  Champlain Towers South collapsed because they didn't slope or waterproof their pool deck, so rainwater sat there and soaked into the concrete, leaching out the lime that kept the re-bar from rusting.   Here, the Building Integrity Youtube channel does a great job of covering this (esp: regarding Champlain Towers), [here's a talk on how concrete dooms steel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65vfMUP4-i8).  (And sea salt is less the issue; Josh is in Miami :)

So now you know why concrete decks have been the ruination of many a museum ship.   Ryan Samansky has a [quick talk on that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17wnf7ehcZw). Railway cars also once used a poured "lightweight concrete" type product for interior floors, and the the effect this has on the structural steel is ghastly.

On your container the rust will mainly happen around the edges of the roof. You will eventually get a "dotted line" of pinhole rust-throughs along that edge -  but really, that is a telltale for the entire edge thinning.  I've had the joy of taking a wire wheel to such areas only to watch the steel immediately blow through *simply from the few pounds of force of the wire wheel* and now I have a hole to patch.

Eventually the roof will collapse along that edge.  Note that is the only thing holding the outer wall vertical, so the wall will be able to kick outward.

So your concrete plan is fine for a *temporary* structure.  (no one ever imagined those ships or railroad cars to be in museums for 60 years). After that, you'll need to frequently and carefully inspect the ceiling of the containers for rust-through.

But you were planning to "finish" the ceiling, correct? How will you inspect it then?

### In the meantime, thermal characteristics will suck

Concrete is a powerful "thermal mass". Having it in direct contact with the container steel means that in mornings, the ceiling will be cold and take into the afternoon before it warms up, making the place cold and clammy - and causing condensation on the ceiling, accelerating water damage and rusting.  Then it will soak up and store solar gain, making it quite warm and taking a long time after sunset to stop radiating heat downward.  So any A/C will have to run late into the night.

### There is no substitute for proper prep and paint

Generally, by the time a shipping container dribbles down into the aftermarket, its paint is starting to have issues. The roof, and particular nooks and crannies on the roof, is a top area of concern.  When paint fails, rust begins.

Like Cher used to say, "if it came in a bottle, everyone would have a great body". The same applies to paint prep - if there was a product that came in a bottle you could just goob on, nothing would be rusty!   So the idea that some magic primer, *or tar, **or concrete***, can be just applied over rust and that will fix it - that's sheer fantasy.  That's not me saying that, [that's NASA](https://corrosion.ksc.nasa.gov) - an organization whose mission is maintaining vast steel structures in a coastal environment, and also has a side gig sending people into space :)

Unfortunately it appears corrosion.ksc.nasa.gov has a new "curator" who has shifted focus from directly sharing their vast research, to simply *bragging about* their vast research. So I can no longer link the data from which I extracted those conclusions; there's [NASA-STD-5008B](https://standards.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/standards/NASA/B-w/CHANGE-1/1/NASA-STD-5008B-Revalidation-w-Change-1.pdf), but it's a shadow of the riches once found on the site. Shameful. Those assets are property of the American people.  Anyway...

What does work is media blast down to SSPC-PC10 near white metal, and again this is NASA talking, followed by appropriate primers. Ideally a mil-spec 2-part epoxy chromate primer, but a quality alkyd primer such as Rustoleum 7769 will do *reasonably* well in my experience - we have one that lasted 30 years with $11/gallon non-lead primer from a local paint factory *because it was blasted to SSPC-PC10*.

In my experience, a reasonable second place is achieved with SSPC-SP3 mechanical wire wheel work; I often get lucky and get the rust to stop with that, good surface cleaning, ideal application conditions and Rustoleum 7769 and a topcoat.  I consider it worth my time to at least try, when media blast is impractical or too much trouble. But I observe it for a couple years to see if it holds or needs re-treatment.

### Do what ships do - wood deck

If it were my project, I would not even bother faffing around with concrete.  I would make sure the container roof drainage is set up properly, make sure it is coated correctly, and then, install a wood deck or Trex.   *I don't think you need teak, though. That's for salt spray.*

A wood deck is also good [for insulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIteMpyHb48).

Comment: but I worry about the water pooling under the deck and being unable to evaporate fast enough.

Comment: @Jasen that's why the drainage needs to be tip top before you start.  Also mosquitos.  Teak is also for warships and museum ships are [contending with the results of poorly chosen substitutions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIteMpyHb48).   Note also the insulating properties of a wood deck; a concrete deck will be a huge "thermal mass" tightly coupled to the skin of the container, and that seems quite bad actually. Coldness and ceiling condensation in morning and early afternoon, and oppressive heat long into the evening.

Comment: containers are made with roofs that collect pools of water.

Comment: @Jasen That would necessitate extra paint prep attention, and the drainage issue should be resolved with drains as needed.  It's not just the future rust from standing water: it's the mosquitoes!  How come nobody uses boxcars -- they have slanted roofs that are properly designed for drainage.

Answer (score 0):

The container roof is not as strong as believed.  If you look at the way they are stacked, the weight is transferred through the corners.  I have had a number of them in the past for storage and have climbed up and painted them.  I would not call them strong, nor would I trust the weight f concrete on top of them,

> **What is the weight limit for a shipping container roof?**
> The standard roof for a shipping container is 1,000 lb (450 kg) maximum. This is the weight that is typically used for roofing materials, so it is a good idea to keep your roofing load at or below this weight limit. Anything over this weight limit can cause the roof to collapse, which can be very dangerous.

> **How much weight can a 20ft shipping container roof support?**
> A 20-foot shipping container roof can support between 15 and 20 pounds per square foot, depending on the type of container and the materials used in its construction. The weight capacity of a container roof is important to consider when determining how many goods or materials can be stored inside. The load bearing capacity of a container roof is also a factor to consider when determining the best way to stack containers for shipping or storage.

From [How much weight can a shipping container roof support?](https://www.cgaa.org/articles/how-much-weight-can-a-shipping-container-roof-support)

There are ready-made roof kits available to protect the container roof

1. [The 4 Best Shipping Container Roof Kits and Covers for 2023](https://www.containeraddict.com/shipping-container-roof-kit/)
2. [Container Roof Panels](https://ancdist.co.nz/cargo-solutions/container-solutions/container-sheets-panels/container-roof-panels/)